# How to handle some null entries when populating entity model from multiple linq

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I am populating a viewmodel from two queries:

Model:
    Student (Name, teacher, HomeroomName, HomeRoomLocation)

The two queries are for the student table, and the Homeroom table.  It is possible and ok for the student to not have a homeroom assigned.

```
var student = context.Student.where(c => c.stuid == studentId).SingleOrDefault();

var homeroom = context.HomeRoom.where(c => c.stuid == studentId).SingleOrDefault();

if(student != null)
{ 
   Student student = new Student
   {
     Name = student.Name,
     Teacher = student.Teacher.Name,
     HomeRoomName = homeroom.Name,
     HomeRoomLocation = homeroom.Location
   };
}
```

If the homeroom query is null, which is totally fine per the business rules, everything blows up.  I could have a bunch of if conditions and return a single model, but I would rather do it in one shot.

Can  I do inline ?? in the model population?  Like

```
HomeRoom = homeroom.Name == null ? null : homeroom.Name,
```

Comment: Using `HomeRoom = homeroom.Name == null ? null : homeroom.Name` makes no sense, it's the same thing as `HomeRoom = homeroom.Name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to check is if `homeroom` variable is `null` or not:

```
HomeRoom = homeroom == null ? null : homeroom.Name,
```

In C# 6.0 you can use [*Null-Conditional Operator*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx):

```
HomeRoom = homeroom?.Name,
```

The null-conditional operator checks whether the operand (in this case `homeroom` variable) is `null` prior to invoking the `Name` property.The logically equivalent explicit code would be the following:

```
(homeroom!= null) ? homeroom.Name : null
```

Answer (score 2):

This will allow you to check both variables for null, and create your object, or create a student with no homeroom if the homeroom is null.

```
if (student != null & homeRoom != null) {
    Student student = new Student {
        Name = student.Name,
        Teacher = student.Teacher.Name,
        HomeRoomName = homeroom.Name,
        HomeRoomLocation = homeroom.Location
    };
} else if (student != null) {
    Student student = new Student {
        Name = student.Name,
        Teacher = student.Teacher.Name
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why you don't create a constructor inside your `Student` class?

```
public Student() {
}

public Student(Student student, HomeRoom homeroom) {
    this.Name = student.Name;
    this.Teacher = student.Teacher.Name;

    if(homeroom != null) {
        this.HomeRoomName = homeroom.Name;
        this.HomeRoomLocation = homeroom.Location;
    }
}
```

So you can use like this:

```
var newStudent = new Student(student, homeroom);
```